# T-SQL Stored Procedure - Dynamic AND/OR Operator

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am just wondering if there is a way in MS SQL Server 2005 to pass an operator in as a stored proc parameter. I really need to avoid using Dynamic SQL if that is even possible.

```
@AppOperator = "AND"

WHERE (1 = 1) @AppOperator (2 = 2)
```

Comment: Not sure if you'll be able to have a query that has the operator dynamically assigned without dynamic sql (be happy to find out otherwise).  If dynamic SQL is not possible, would it be possible to setup two nearly identical statements, one with the where or and the other where and, with an if statement to determine which one to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really what you might want (because expressions have to be repeated), but this works:

```
@AppOperator = "AND"

...
WHERE (
      @AppOperator = "AND" AND ((1 = 1) AND (2 = 2))
      OR
      @AppOperator = "OR" AND ((1 = 1) OR (2 = 2))
)
...
```

Comment: This will have to work. Thank god I only have one expression to repeat. Thanks for the help!