# Pass operator to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app that lets users to create their own filters. Something like `amount > 5 and amount <= 7`, and so on. The user can choose both the amount value and the operator.

My problem is how to pass those filters to the stored procedure that retrieves the data. The stored procedure is already pretty complicated, meaning there are a lot of parameters passed which are checked to be null, so I can't really apply the answer I found here: [T-SQL Stored Procedure - Dynamic AND/OR Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540149/t-sql-stored-procedure-dynamic-and-or-operator)

Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operators cannot be parameterized. Since you mention this is a stored procedure, the only option is to write the T-SQL inside the SP, and use sp_executesql, i.e.

```
//TODO : verify (whitelist) that @operator is in a known set of values...
// '=', '<>', '>', '<' etc - otherwise security risk
declare @sql varchar(4000) = 'select * from Foo where Bar '
          + @operator + ' @value'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@value int', @value
```

This builds the query (`@sql`) on the fly, but keeps the value (`@value`) parameterized throughout, so we only need to white-list the operator (`@operator`).

Just to show how the value remains parameterized, we could also have used:

```
//TODO : verify (whitelist) that @operator is in a known set of values...
// '=', '<>', '>', '<' etc - otherwise security risk
declare @sql varchar(4000) = 'select * from Foo where Bar '
          + @operator + ' @p'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@p int', @value
```

Here, `@p` is the name of the parameter in the **inner** sql, and `@value` is the name of the parameter in the *stored procedure*; the third/fourth/fifth/etc parameters to `sp_executesql` are mapped to the parameters declared in the *second* parameter to `sp_executesql` (which in this example, declared just `@p`).

Note that if this wasn't a stored procedure, you could perform the query-construction step in C#, again keeping the value as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to use dynamic sql, e.g., [sq_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). This allows you to create your SQL statement as a string, and then execute it. But it will probably mean a lot of rewriting of your existing stored procedure!